# HTMLAudioElement.currentTime is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-audio

I'm using an range slider `<input>` element inside a React component to scrub/seek through an HTML5 `<audio>` element.

see the shortened code of the component:

```
class Player extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {

    if(this.player) {
      this.player.addEventListener("timeupdate", e => {
        this.props.update_time(e.target.currentTime)
        this.props.set_duration(e.target.duration)
        this.timeBar.value = e.target.currentTime
      });

      this.timeBar.addEventListener("change", e => {
        console.log(this.player)
        this.player.currentTime(e.target.value)
      })
    }
  }


  render() {

      return (
        <div className="player">
        <input
          type="range"
          id="seek"
          defaultValue={this.props.time}
          max={this.props.duration}
          ref={ref => this.timeBar = ref}
        />
          <audio ref={ref => this.player = ref} >
            <source
              src={this.props.url}
              type="audio/mpeg"
            />
          </audio>
        </div>
      )
  }
}
```

If I move the slider (thus triggering the "change" event), I get the following error:

```
TypeError: this.player.currentTime is not a function
```

However, if I try to set the currentTime value directly in the console on the object that is returned by `console.log(this.player)` it works perfectly fine.

I tried pretty much everything and ran out ouf ideas. The file is fully loaded, the server supports streaming, the this.player object is returned correctly, even inside the event listener.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: As the error message says, [`HTMLMediaElement.currentTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime) is not a function, it is a variable that you could change, eg: `this.player.currentTime = e.target.value;`